# Wieso nennt man Einbrecherfiguren gerne "Ede"?

Tags: etymology

In einer Antwort auf eine Wortverwendungsfrage wurde hier kürzlich ein Textbeispiel angeführt, in dem eine Bande von Einbrechern die nächste Aktion in einer Wohnsiedlung plant (um dabei die Ausdrücke "angefangen von", "angefangen bei" und "angefangen mit" zu analysieren). In der Antwort wurde einer der Einbrecher "Ede" genannt - in bester Tradition solcher leicht romantisierender Schilderungen des Einbrecherwesens.

Daraufhin fing ich an, mich zu fragen, wo der Usus herkommt, in deutschsprachigen Texten Einbrecher typischerweise (und fast schon klischeehaft) "Ede" zu nennen.

Ich vermute, "Ede" soll eine Kurz- und Koseform für "Eduard" sein. Nun ist *Eduard* aber weder ein besonders häufiger Name, noch wäre mir geläufig, dass es unter Personen mit Namen Eduard berühmte Einbrecher gäbe.

Gibt es vielleicht eine literarische Quelle, auf die "Ede" als Einbrechername in narrativen Texten zurückzuführen wäre? Eine bekannte Figur aus Comic und Schaugeschäft? Eine Räuberfigur aus einem Kinderbuch? Der Räuber Hotzenplotz ist es ja nicht... oder hieß er mit vollem Namen Eduard Hotzenplotz?

**Nachtrag**

Erwähnenswert in diesem Zusammenhang ist unbedingt *Ede Wolf*, eine einschläg spezialisierte Unterschichtfigur aus Entenhausen. Ede Wolf ist im englischen Zeke Wolf oder The Big Bad Wolf (http://www.duckipedia.de/Ede_Wolf). Nun mag diese Figur zur Popularität des Namens Ede beigetragen haben, doch würde ich vermuten, dass auch die Benennung in den Disney-Comics, deutsche Ausgabe, sich an literarischen (oder milieusprachlichen?) Vorbildern orientierte, das heißt, der Verweis auf Ede Wolf beantwortet die Frage noch nicht.

**Miszellen**

- Schiller nannte die Hauptfiguren in seinen "Räubern" Franz und Karl. Kann das ein Hinweis sein, dass die Sitte, Kleinkriminelle "Ede" zu nennen, im späten 18. Jahrhundert noch nicht bestand? (Na gut, Schillers Räuber sind nicht unbedingt Kleinkriminelle.)
- Ein Eduard hat eine Hauptrolle in Karl Mays "Buschgespenst" (wo zwar keine Einbrecher vorkommen, dafür aber Schmuggler und organisiertes Verbrechen in den höheren Etagen der Gesellschaft). Dieser Eduard ist aber genau das Gegenbild zu einem Einbrecher: Er ist arm, verhält sich aber ethisch und moralisch vorbildlich (und kriegt darum am Ende auch die Dorfschönheit).
- Wie Kommentator Tofro unten anmerkt: Der Moderator der Verbrecherjagd-Fernsehsendung "Aktenzeichen XY ungelöst", Eduard Zimmermann, wird bisweilen spöttisch *Ganoven-Ede* genannt.

Comment: Ich befürchte, dass das leider keine Frage ist, die genug mit der *deutschen Sprache* zu tun hat, um hierher zu gehören.

Comment: Mit welcher Sprache sollte die Frage sonst zu tun haben? Es ist eine komplett auf den deutschen Sprachraum beschränkte Sitte, Einbrecher "Ede" zu nennen, und man tut dies nur in bestimmten Formen sprachlicher Äußerung, z.B. in Erzählungen, nicht im realen Einbrecher- und Polizeialltag (nehme ich mal an). Es geht um ein Wort (Ede) und seine Herkunft. Ja, es ist keine Frage zur Grammatik, aber durchaus eine zur Pragmatik.

Comment: Ich kann dazu nur beisteuern, dass die Form »Ede« in Österreich als typisch deutsch (im Sinn von »zu Deutschland gehörend«, also als Gegensatz zu *österreichisch*, empfunden wurde und wird). Männer mit dem Vornamen *Eduard* gibt es in Österreich auch, die heißen dann aber *Edi.*

Comment: Wenn von einem Butler die Rede ist, wird er oft *James* genannt, und ein Ober in einem Wiener Kaffeehaus hieß von Berufs wegen *Herr Joseph*. Die typische Dienstmagd hieß *Sophie*, und der Hausdiener war der *Herr Leopold*. Solche archetypischen Vornamen waren früher sehr weit verbreitet, sind heute aber kaum noch gebräuchlich.

Comment: Vgl. auch Udl, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udel_(Spottname), wie in "Wenn der Udl ums Eck kommt, nimmt der Ede reißaus, weil der Ede den Udl nicht mag. …"

Comment: Es handelt sich um einen Namen - und die sind sprachunabhängig, und um den Usus, zu wem dieser Name *passt* - Das hat für mich nur wenig mit Sprache zu tun, sondern eher mit Gesellschaft und Kultur. Diese Frage passt (wiederum: für mich) genausowenig hierher wie die Frage, warum die Briten Porridge zum Frühstück essen, in eine englische Sprachcommunity passt.

Comment: @tofro - Warum die Briten porridge *essen*, würde auch ich eher in einem Forum zur europäischen Agrargeschichte diskutieren. Warum sie es aber porridge *nennen* - da fällt mir kein besseres Forum ein als eins zur englischen Sprache.

Comment: Ich hatte angenommen, daß es sich hauptsächlich um eine Alliteration handelt –wie **B**ob der **B**aumeister. Auf thinkbabynames.com und namensbedeutung.de steht aber, daß ‚Ede‘ bzw. ‚Eduard‘ aus dem Altenglischen kommen (genau wie @tofro Porridge) und soviel bedeuten wie: ‚to strife for wealth‘. Das beschreibt ja nun einen Einbrecher ganz gut. Es könnte Zufall sein, aber das glaube ich nicht. Außerdem habe ich noch ein Buch entdeckt (Das Große L, von Ute Andresen) mit einer Geschichte über ‚Einbrecher Ede‘. Das Buch ist aus den 70ern, der Sprachgebrauch also wahrscheinlich älter.

Comment: @MarkOxford - Dein Kommentar wäre es wert, als Antwort eingetragen zu werden. Alliteration: *Einbrecher Ede* ist unbedingt ein Argument, und dann noch die Bedeutung von "Eduard" als "reichtumssuchend"... das klingt alles nach einer soliden ususgeschichtlichen Rekonstruktion.

Comment: Eduard Zimmermann, der Moderator der TV-Show "Aktenzeichen XY ungelöst" (sowas wie *Crimewatch* or *Unsolved Mysteries*) wurde "Ganoven-Ede" genannt.

Comment: Mir roch der Ede nach Berthold Brecht, und tatsächlich findet sich in der 3-Groschenoper ein Ede, aber nur als eine Randfigur, etwa im Ggs. zu Mecki Messer. WP: "Die Platte: Münz-Matthias, Hakenfinger-Jakob, Säge-Robert, Ede, Jimmy, Trauerweiden-Walter". NGram weist um 1900 einen zweiten Peak-Ede aus, um 1800 einen ersten. Die Fundstellenbetrachtung fördert dann aber nur Artefakte (Silben, Sperrschrift) und Sackgassen (Gerhard Hauptmann, Roter Hahn, ein Ede aber kein Dieb o.ä.) zu Tage.

Comment: @MarkOxford : ich dachte erst 'strife' sei ein Übertragungsfehler, und gemeint sei 'strive'(streben) - aber tatsächlich, mehrere Onlinequellen geben 'strife' (Streit, Kampf) an. Das passt zwar eigentlich besser zu einem Räuber, aber vielleicht ist die Unterscheidung Dieb/Räuber in der Person des Ede auch nicht gegeben. Ich glaube auch fiktionale Bankräuber dieses Namens gesehen zu haben.

Answer (score 10):

Eine Herkunftsverbindung zum späten 20. Jahrhundert einschließlich des [Ganoven-Ede genannten Fernsehmachers](https://www.jurablogs.com/go/ede-war-kein-waisenknabe), scheint mir viel zu spät.

Ein wesentlich früheres Beispiel für einen Einbrecher mit Namen Ede:

> [In der Gemeinschaft mit Pagels und Hink-Ede war er in das Haus der Klosterstraße eingebrochen, während Schiel-August, der wegen natürlicher Mißbildung um die Ecke zu sehen vermochte, Schmiere stand.](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/emma-das-geheimnissvolle-hausmadchen-3151/37) (1904)

Was einen Ursprung im Rotwelsch vermuten lässt:

Interessant ist da die Herkunft des Bestandteils -Ede als Ableitung von [Edgar](http://www.erdbeerlounge.de/mami/vornamen/ede/):

> altenglisch: „der Besitz“, „das Vermögen“, „wertvoll“

Und dazu diesebeiden Lexikaeinträge:

> [Deutsches Rechtswörterbuch (DRW): 
> Ede](http://drw-www.adw.uni-heidelberg.de/drw-cgi/zeige?db=drw&index=lemmata&term=Ede&darstellung=%DC)  – rotwelsch: Freund, Genosse 
>   [Wilhelm Polzer: "Ganovenwörterbuch für den Kriminalpraktiker" (1922)](https://books.google.de/books/about/Gauner_W%C3%B6rterbuch_f%C3%BCr_den_Kriminalprak.html?id=7zBsAAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y): 
>   Ed – Zeuge, Freund, Genosse, Partner im Spiel 
>   Ed Schecker – falscher Zeuge 
>   Ede – siehe Ed

Ein Rekurs auf Literatur scheint mir weniger fruchtbar als [Polizei- und Gerichtssprache](https://books.google.de/books?id=lwHpBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA250&lpg=PA250&dq=zangen-ede&source=bl&ots=fQehOS74nG&sig=hEpF7REeTlzrjtyZrTPk1ZltAc4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkxLjpjcvXAhXEChoKHYR9C4kQ6AEIzAEwCg#v=onepage&q=zangen-ede&f=false). Als Namensbildungsform für Randgruppen sind diese Muster wohl bis ins Mittelalter zu verfolgen. Müller-Josch, Pistolen-Ede, Greifer-Karl etc.

Eine spezielle Prominenz des "Einbrecher Edes" ist wohl nur auf die Alliterationseffekte bei Kreation und Erinnerung zu suchen. Nicht aber in den zuerst aufgetretenen Realfiguren.

Auffallend scheint mir, dass ich selbst tatsächlich drei Personen kenne, deren Spitzname Ede lautet, dieser aber jeweils *nichts* mit dem Realnamen zu tun hat. In einem Fall ist jedenfalls ein Christian gebürtiger Berliner.

Ein weiterer Aspekt, der beachtenswert scheint, sind stereotype (Spitz-)Namensgebungen in 'niederer' Literatur:

> [Über die Namen im Kriminalroman der Gegenwart (1965):](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01514843?LI=true)
>   Wie bereits Hugo, Mario und Gustav zeigen, ergreifen die Kriminalschmöker diese Ausdrucksmöglichkeiten gerne. Ein besonderes Feld bilden die Ganovennamen, die z.T. alt und z.T. international verbreitet sind; die ältesten Belege sind die Namen der Gefährten Meier Helmbrechts im 13. Jahrhundert. Manchmal sieht man es einem Namen an, auf welchen Schauplätzen ihre Träger operieren. Jack Spot Comer ist ein „König der Londoner Unterwelt,“ während **Ede und die spezielleren Muskel-Adolf, Klamotten-Emil und Mollen-Albert in Berlin agieren.**

Comment: Es war nicht insinuiert, dass der Spitzname *Ganoven-Ede* des Fernsehmoderators Zimmermann ursächlich sein könnte für die Verbreitung der Verwendung von "Ede" für Kleinkriminielle.  Der *Ganoven-Ede* diente nur zur Illustration, dass "Ede" in diesem Kontext populär ist.

Comment: Interessant finde ich, dass du in der Tat drei Leute kennst, die Ede genannt werden. (In welchen Kreisen verkehrst du?) Scherz beiseite: Ich kenne keinen einzigen realen "Ede". Wie Hubert kenne ich jedoch immerhin einen "Edi" (der ist aber nicht Einbrecher sondern Orgelbauer), und die Gegend, in der er wohnt, ist in Hörweite von Österreich. Ich kenne jedoch in der gleichen Gegend auch Leute, die "Manne" (von Manfred) und "Gege" (von Gerhard) gerufen werden - interessanterweise aber eben nicht "Manni" oder "Gegi".

Answer (score 4):

[Auf Christian Geiselmanns Anregung darf ich meinen Kommentar noch etwas ausführen.]

Zunächst fällt bei *Einbrecher Ede* auf, daß es sich um eine Alliteration handelt – wie etwa auch bei **B**ob dem **B**aumeister oder **J**udge **J**udy. Das ist zwar bei ‚typischen‘ Vornamen nicht immer der Fall; z.B. heißt der Butler *James* und nicht *Bob*. Dennoch hilft so eine Alliteration sicher dabei, den Namen einzubürgern.

Vielleicht wichtiger ist die Namensbedeutung: *Eduard* kommt aus dem Altenglischen und bedeutet soviel wie ‚strife for wealth‘ oder ‚guardian of wealth‘. (Siehe z.B. [hier](http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Ede) und [hier](http://www.namen-namensbedeutung.de/Namen/Namen-Ede.html)) Beides beschreibt einen Einbrecher, wenn vielleicht auch nur auf ironische Weise.

Das Problem ist, daß die meisten Leute natürlich nicht wissen, woher *Eduard* kommt. Wenn es also darum geht, warum sich *Eduard* als Name für Einbrecher eingebürgert hat, dann hilft die Namensherkunft nur bedingt weiter.

Interessant ist die Geschichte von *Edward dem Bekenner*: nach seiner Krönung zum Englischen König (1043) **beraubte** er seine eigene Mutter ihrer Reichtümer und Ländereien. Allerdings habe ich im Englischen noch nie davon gehört, daß Diebe ‚Edward‘ heißen. (Ich lebe in England.)

In den Kommentaren ist bereits auf Ganoven-Ede hingewiesen worden: Eduard Zimmermann war der Moderator der Fernsehserien *Aktenzeichen XY … Ungelöst* und *Vorsicht Falle – Nepper, Schlepper, Bauernfänger*. Laut Wikipedia war er überdies in der Nachkriegszeit selbst als ‚Ganove‘ tätig. Jedenfalls wird die Sendung dazu beigetragen haben, daß *Ede* zum Einbrechernamen geworden ist.

Zuletzt habe ich noch ein Buch entdeckt: *Das Große L* von Ute Andresen. Dies enthält eine Geschichte über ‚Einbrecher Ede‘ und stammt aus den 70ern. Wahrscheinlich ist also, daß *Ede* zu dem Zeitpunkt schon als Einbrechername etabliert war.

Answer (score -2):

In einem 1979 herausgegebenen, in 80ern populären Kinderbuch kommt der "Einbrecher Ede" vor. Soweit keine älteren Quellen vorliegen können wir davon ausgehen dass dies die Präzedenz für den heutigen Gebrauch ist.

Comment: Und der Titel und Autor des Buches wären... ?

Comment: Ask Google? Erscheint nicht zufällig ganz oben?

Comment: Google frag ich nicht so gern. Lieber hier auf die Seite schreiben. Denn wenn dann mal der Strom ausfällt, hat man's hier wenigstens schwarz auf weiß.